# How to pass geolocation permission to react-native-webview?

Tags: ios, react-native, permissions, geolocation, react-native-webview

When using the geolcoation api in a react-native-webview, I am asked twice whether the app is allowed to use my current location. How is it possible to forward the already (not) granted permission to the webview?

I am currently using react-native 0.68 and react-native-webview 11.22.

First prompt:

[image: first promt]

Second prompt:

[image]

I should only be asked once for permission to use my current geolocation.

Comment: No, you will be asked twice. A web view is not your native app. It is the same as accessing a web page that wants your location. The user can go into safari settings and allow web sites to use location without asking but there is nothing you can do in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case somebody faces the same problem, I solved this issue with the following workaround. I injected a custome javacscript into the webview to override the used geolocation api in the webview. My custome script does all the communication with the app. The app returns the geolocation and so the webview doesn't need to aks for permission.

**Custome Script**

```html
export const getGeoLocationJS = () => {
  const getCurrentPosition = `
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = (success, error, options) => {
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ event: 'getCurrentPosition', options: options }));

      window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
        let eventData = {}
        try {
          eventData = JSON.parse(e.data);
        } catch (e) {}

        if (eventData.event === 'currentPosition') {
          success(eventData.data);
        } else if (eventData.event === 'currentPositionError') {
          error(eventData.data);
        }
      });
    };
    true;
  `;

  const watchPosition = `
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition = (success, error, options) => {
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ event: 'watchPosition', options: options }));

      window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
        let eventData = {}
        try {
          eventData = JSON.parse(e.data);
        } catch (e) {}

        if (eventData.event === 'watchPosition') {
          success(eventData.data);
        } else if (eventData.event === 'watchPositionError') {
          error(eventData.data);
        }
      });
    };
    true;
  `;

  const clearWatch = `
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch = (watchID) => {
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ event: 'clearWatch', watchID: watchID }));
    };
    true;
  `;

  return `
    (function() {
      ${getCurrentPosition}
      ${watchPosition}
      ${clearWatch}
    })();
  `;
};
```

**Webview**

```html
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

let webview = null;

<WebView
  geolocationEnabled={ true }
  injectedJavaScript={ getGeoLocationJS() }
  javaScriptEnabled={ true }
  onMessage={ event => {
    let data = {}
    try {
      data = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    if (data?.event && data.event === 'getCurrentPosition') {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        webview.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ event: 'currentPosition', data: position }));
      }, (error) => {
        webview.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ event: 'currentPositionError', data: error }));
      }, data.options);
    } else if (data?.event && data.event === 'watchPosition') {
      Geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
        webview.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ event: 'watchPosition', data: position }));
      }, (error) => {
        webview.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ event: 'watchPositionError', data: error }));
      }, data.options);
    } else if (data?.event && data.event === 'clearWatch') {
      Geolocation.clearWatch(data.watchID);
    } 
  }}
  ref={ ref => {
    webview = ref;
    if (onRef) {
      onRef(webview)
    }
  }}
  source={ url }
  startInLoadingState={ true }
/>
```

Comment: Smart solution, did you have any issues with Apple Review using this? Thanks for sharing!

Comment: No, not at all. I have been using injected js for communicating between webview and mobile device for quite a while. This is just an unusual case now, but it got accepted right away.

Comment: Where does the onRef() function come from and what does it do?